# How to open 2 web pages sequentially in CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I want to open webpage1 do some tests and later open webpage2

```
casper.start('http://localhost/awesome_page1', initialize);

casper.then(function () {
    casper.test.assertHttpStatus(200);
});

// tasks completed in first webpage

casper.start('http://localhost/awesome_page2', initialize);

casper.then(function () {
    casper.test.assertHttpStatus(200);
});

casper.run(function () {
   casper.test.done();
});
```

When I am executing the code only the second webpage2 is opening. How to solve this?

Comment: @ArtjomB. Accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the answer is right there on the Casper's main page - use `thenOpen`:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start('http://casperjs.org/');

casper.then(function() {
    this.echo('First Page: ' + this.getTitle());
});

casper.thenOpen('http://phantomjs.org', function() {
    this.echo('Second Page: ' + this.getTitle());
});

casper.run();
```